# How to deal with colons ":" in filename in shell script

Tags: macos, bash, shell

I have a large group of files with ":" in their file names.  When I'm in the interactive shell,  typing "\" and then hitting tab does the trick to get them recognized as valid inputs to commands, but not so in the shell script.

I've tried

```
less file:name.txt
less file\:name.txt
less 'file\:name.txt
less 'file:name.txt'
```

and it's not recognized as a valid file.

However on the interactive command line I type less, followed by first file, then I type \, and then hit the TAB key, everything then works...

How do I do this in the shell script?

Comment: The reason the shell wants to escape these in interactive use is that there are completion functions for `tar` archives, `ssh` path names etc in which the colon is significant.  Backslashing in interactive use is harmless (except when the completion functions are buggy and outsmart themselves by adding more quoting when it isn't necessary) but not strictly necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double quotes:

```
less "file:name.txt"
```

Bash recognizes the value within the double quotes as a full string.

As seen in [Using quotes to include spaces and characters in filenames](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/Quote.html#uh-3):

> If you want to work with files with spaces or special characters in
>   the filename, you may have to use quotes.

Comment: Don't understand why other people is posting the same answer after mine.

Answer (score 0):

This is working even when you don't put anything.

you can try:
less file and it recognizes it for you...

But you can use `less "file:name.txt"` as string in your bash.